# Inclusion of Power Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the Power set of a set $P(A)$ always a subset of the second Power set of this set $P(P(A))$?

Comment: Yes. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notion of power set, I just wanted to verify my thoughts, thanks.

Comment: By "included", do you mean as a subset or as an element?

Comment: I mean that  , $P(A) \subset P(P(A))$ , every element of $P(A)$ is still in $P(P(A))$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is usually not true.  For instance, if $A=\{x\}$ has one element, then $$P(A)=\{\emptyset,\{x\}\}$$ and $$P(P(A))=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\},\{\{x\}\},\{\emptyset,\{x\}\}\}.$$

If $P(A)$ is a subset of $P(P(A))$, that means that $\{x\}$ must be equal to one of the four elements of $P(P(A))$.  Since $\{x\}$ is a set with one element, the only elements of $P(P(A))$ it could be equal to are $\{\emptyset\}$ and $\{\{x\}\}$, and it is only equal to one of them if either $x=\emptyset$ or $x=\{x\}$.  In set theory we usually don't allow sets to be elements of themselves, so $x=\{x\}$ is impossible (and even if we do allow sets to be elements of themselves, most of them aren't!).  So if $x$ is anything at all other than the empty set, $P(A)$ is not a subset of $P(P(A))$.

Answer (score 0):

The powerset of any set contains all subsets of that set i.e. $If X\subseteq Y$ then $X\in P(Y)$, especially $Y\subseteq Y$ and thus $Y\in P(Y)$.

In this case $Y= P(A)$ and thus $P(A)\in P(P(A))$

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a set, the powerset $P(X)$ (also denoted $2^{X}$) is the collection of all subsets of $X\ .$ Since $X$ is a subset of itself, $X$ is an *element* of the collection $P(X)\ ;$ it is important to keep in mind that elements of $P(X)$ are subsets of $X\ .$

Since $P(X)$ is a subset of itself, $P(X)$ is an element of the collection $P(P(X))\ .$

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?

Comment: @NoahSchweber It doesn't answer the question. OP asks to show that $P(X)$ is a $\textit{subset}$ of $P(P(X))$ (which isn't always true, of course), not an $\textit{element of}$.

Comment: Additionally, $2^X$ is usually the notation reserved for the collection of functions from $X$ to the set $\{0,1\}$, not the powerset. They are sets that have the same cardinality, yes, but they are not the same set.

Comment: @Nectric. I guess you regard my effort to help OP as either an egregiously sloppy no-effort-expended post or as possibly dangerously incorrect. If not, then you are not following the guidelines for down-voting which state "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."

Comment: @AndersMuszta Unfortunately it appears that my comments imply that I down-voted. I did not.  I only pushed forward an effort to answer Mr. Schweber's question. It would've been more helpful if you replied or changed your post, but you decided cite a guideline (which I still find helpful, for I would like to be more accustomed to the guidelines :) ). For what it's worth (which isn't probably much), I find that rule in the guideline to be a bit exaggerated. I'm sure even moderators or persons with high reputation down-vote for lesser reasons.

Comment: @Nectric. Very well, I understand. Thank you for the clarification. As for altering my post, it would make the discussion following it look strange to an outside reader.

Comment: @AndersMuszta You're welcome, and okay :).